# how to access a member/element of an stdClass Object?

Tags: php, json

I need to access the member/element of an stdClass Object, my response is in json_decode I need to access some specific element from the result here is my response

```
stdClass Object
(
    [status] => 200
    [result] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [postcode] => AB10 1XG
                    [quality] => 1
                    [eastings] => 393149
                    [northings] => 805924
                    [country] => Scotland
                    [nhs_ha] => Grampian
                    [longitude] => -2.1148480012509
                    [latitude] => 57.14416009476
                    [parliamentary_constituency] => Aberdeen South
                    [european_electoral_region] => Scotland
                    [primary_care_trust] => Aberdeen City Community Health   Partnership
                    [region] => 
                    [lsoa] => West End North - 01
                    [msoa] => West End North
                    [nuts] => Gilcomston
                    [incode] => 1XG
                    [outcode] => AB10
                    [distance] => 0.564254268
                    [admin_district] => Aberdeen City
                    [parish] => 
                    [admin_county] => 
                    [admin_ward] => Midstocket/Rosemount
                    [ccg] => Aberdeen City Community Health Partnership
                    [codes] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [admin_district] => S12000033
                            [admin_county] => S99999999
                            [admin_ward] => S13002482
                            [parish] => S99999999
                            [ccg] => S03000012
                        )

                )
```

Now I need postcode in a variable

Comment: you can access any member of an object using the -> operator, you should really read the manual before asking questions :) 

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php

Answer (score 1):

You can access it with

```
$variable->status
```

with accessing result which is an array you can loop it or just

```
$array->result[0]->postcode
```

Or you can

```
json_decode($json, true);
```

and it returns an array.

Comment: it is  json_decode($json, true);  not json_deconde($json, true);

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve by this.

```
$array->result[0]->postcode;
```

Comment: but it returns nothing

Comment: have you used json_decode(); on your result? and this will be you variable

Comment: $array->result is an array you need $array->result[0]->postcode

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for this, first I need to convert it into array then I can fetch easily any member or element,

```
$value = get_object_vars($decodedvalues);
$val =  $value['result']['0']['postcode'];
```

And also Thanks all my friends for your support !